# How to make a python multi-threading scraper as a websocket server

Tags: python, asynchronous, websocket, python-asyncio, python-multithreading

I currently have a python **multi-threading** scraper that looks like following, how can I turn this into a **websocket server** so that it can push message once the scraper found some new data? Most websocket implementations that I found are asynchronous using asyncio and I don't want to rewrite all of my codes for that.

Are there any websocket implementations that I can use without rewriting my multi-threading codes into async version? Thanks!

```
from threading import Thread

Class Scraper:
    def _send_request(self):
        response = requests.get(url)
        if response.status_code == 200 and 'good' in response.json():
            send_ws_message()
    
    def scrape(self):
        while True:
            Thread(target=self._send_request).start()
            time.sleep(1)

scraper = Scraper()
scraper.scrape()
```